# Falied to execute script при сохранение PyInstaller в режиме без консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

У меня есть проект (uiPre.py) на питоне, который я захотел скомпилировать в .exe. Я решил использовать PyInstaller:

```
PyInstaller -F -w uiPre.py
```

Он мне выводит вот такие логи

```
(venv) C:\Users\mamet\PycharmProjects\QRgenerator>PyInstaller -F -w uiPre.py
69 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
69 INFO: Python: 3.7.6
70 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
71 INFO: wrote C:\Users\mamet\PycharmProjects\QRgenerator\uiPre.spec
74 INFO: UPX is not available.
76 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\mamet\\PycharmProjects\\QRgenerator',
 'C:\\Users\\mamet\\PycharmProjects\\QRgenerator']
84 INFO: checking Analysis
164 INFO: checking PYZ
188 INFO: checking PKG
238 INFO: Building because C:\Users\mamet\PycharmProjects\QRgenerator\build\uiPre\uiPre.exe.manifest changed
239 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
4493 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
4538 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\mamet\pycharmprojects\qrgenerator\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
4538 INFO: checking EXE
4549 INFO: Rebuilding EXE-00.toc because uiPre.exe missing
4549 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
4549 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\mamet\PycharmProjects\QRgenerator\dist\uiPre.exe
4566 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Но когда я запускаю полученный exe (`uiPre.exe test.pdf`), то он мне выдаёт ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Falied to execute script <script_name>`

Но если при создании exe убрать флаг -w, то все работает нормально, окно появляется.
Попытка запуска с -F без -w пользу не принесла.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А где код самой программы?

Comment: Честно говоря не думал что в нем дело, т.к. он через питон запускается нормально. Но если нужно, то [вот](https://pastebin.com/W8ck3bM1) он

Comment: Я запросил код для того, что бы убедиться, что там есть функция `print`. Как вы думаете, куда именно она выводит переданные аргументы?